# try catch or type conversion performance in julia - (Julia 73 seconds, Python 0.5 seconds)

Tags: performance, type-conversion, try-catch, julia

I have been playing with Julia because it seems syntactically similar to python (which I like) but claims to be faster.  However, I tried making a similar script to something I have in python for tesing where numerical values are within a text file which uses this function:

```
function isFloat(s)
    try:
        float64(s)
        return true
    catch:
        return false
    end
end
```

For some reason, this takes a great deal of time for a text file with a reasonable amount of rows of text (~500000).
Why would this be? Is there a better way to do this? What general feature of the language can I understand from this to apply to other languages?

Here are the two exact scripts i ran with the times for reference:

python: ~0.5 seconds

```
def is_number(s):
    try:
        np.float64(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

start = time.time()
file_data = open('SMW100.asc').readlines()
file_data = map(lambda line: line.rstrip('\n').replace(',',' ').split(), file_data)

bools = [(all(map(is_number, x)), x) for x in file_data]
print time.time() - start
```

julia: ~73.5 seconds

```
start = time()
function isFloat(s)
    try:
        float64(s)
        return true
    catch:
        return false
    end
end
x = map(x-> split(replace(x, ",", " ")), open(readlines, "SMW100.asc"))

u = [(all(map(isFloat, i)), i) for i in x]

print(start - time())
```

Comment: I don't know about the try/catch performance, but to check if a given file has only floats you can try to use the readdlm function (http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/base/#Base.readdlm) which will return an Array{Float64} in the case it is possible (then you can just check for the type of the returned Array).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note also that you can use the [float64_isvalid](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/base/?highlight=float64_isvalid#Base.float64_isvalid) function in the standard library to (a) check whether a string is a valid floating-point value and (b) return the value.

Note also that the colons (`:`) after `try` and `catch` in your `isFloat` code are wrong in Julia (this is a Pythonism).

A much faster version of your code should be:

```
const isFloat2_out = [1.0]
isFloat2(s::String) = float64_isvalid(s, isFloat2_out)

function foo(L)
    x = split(L, ",")
    (all(isFloat2, x), x)
end

u = map(foo, open(readlines, "SMW100.asc"))
```

On my machine, for a sample file with 100,000 rows and 10 columns of data, 50% of which are valid numbers, your Python code takes 4.21 seconds and my Julia code takes 2.45 seconds.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I tried just removing the `:` and it sped it up from 73 seconds to 0.6 seconds, so that was a major issue.  It would be useful if it threw an error about using `:` in the wrong place if it causes that much trouble but still oddly compiles.

Comment: The need for a `const` declaration in your code is odd to me as a non CS person. I know Julia has some issues with global variables, which `isFloat2_out` appears to be, but also I am confused as to why this function is written in this way.  Is it an in-place modification of `isFloat2_out`? What would be wrong about using it to return a boolean value like `b = float64_isvalid("1.2")` to be used like `u = [(all(map(float64_isvalid, i)), i) for i in x]`?

Comment: I want to know what `:` does do here. `:something` makes a symbol `:(1 + 1)` quotes the code returning `(+(1,1))`. Okay, I've got it. In this case what happens? Here's a strange example: `julia> try : println("hi") ; return true end`. This returns `false` for no reason I can imagine.

Comment: It's as if he had typed `try Colon() ; float64(s) ; return true ; catch Colon() ; return false end`. So here's a question: Why does `Colon()` take so long to do nothing?

Answer (score 5):

This is an interesting performance problem that might be worth submitting to julia-users to get more focused feedback than SO will probably provide. At a first glance, I think you're hitting problems because (1) try/catch is just slightly slow to begin with and then (2) you're using try/catch in a context where there's a very considerable amount of type uncertainty because of lots of function calls that don't return stable types. As a result, the Julia interpreter spend its time trying to figure out the types of objects rather than doing your computation. It's a bit hard to tell exactly where the big bottlenecks are because you're doing a lot of things that are not very idiomatic in Julia. Also you seem to be doing your computations in the global scope, where Julia's compiler can't perform many meaningful optimizations due to additional type uncertainty.

Answer (score 3):

Python is oddly ambiguous on the subject of whether using exceptions for control flow is good or bad. See [Python using exceptions for control flow considered bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274310/python-using-exceptions-for-control-flow-considered-bad). But even in Python, the consensus is that user code shouldn't use exceptions for control flow (although for some reason generators are allowed to do this). So basically, the simple answer is that you should not be doing that – exceptions are for exceptional situations, not for control flow. That is why almost zero effort has been put into making Julia's try/catch construct faster – you shouldn't be using it like that in the first place. Of course, we will probably get around to making it faster at some point.

That said, the onus is on us as the designers of Julia's standard library to make sure that we provide APIs that never force you to use exceptions for control flow. In this case, you need a function that allows you to try to parse something as a floating-point value and indicate whether that was possible or not – not by throwing an exception, but rather by returning normal values. We don't provide such an API, so this ultimately a shortcoming of Julia's standard library – as it exists right now. I've opened an issue to discuss this API design question: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/5704. We'll see how it pans out.

Comment: Actually, we do provide such an API in this particular case (`float64_isvalid`), as noted below.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @StefanKarpinski I didn't realize the try catch could be such  bad practice. When I was writing the script in python, I had a feeling that it didn't look like a good solution just because it seemed like a trivial task taken up by multiple user defined lines of code - very rare in python. Yet, everyone assured me that it was the right answer so I kept it - nice to know I wasn't completely wrong.

Comment: Actually, I don't think Python is ambiguous at all.  It's a common, accepted, and even promoted idiom.  One of the Python core dev's sums it up much better than I could in his answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16138232/is-it-a-good-practice-to-use-try-except-else-in-python)

Comment: Thanks for the link. In that case, that's a fairly significant philosophical difference between Python and Julia.