# Set up a Python list from possibly non-existing variables

Tags: python

Inside a Python class, I have to do multiple checks for several private variables, e. g. `self.__a`, `self.__b` and `self.__c` that are contained inside a list. The procedure would then start like this:

```
   for var in [self.__a, self.__b, self.__c]:
       ...
```

My problem now is, that some (and possibly all) of the variables contained inside the list might have not been set up by now, and my program stops due to the occurring `AttributeError`.

The only way I figured out to set up this list so that it contains only the variables that already exist is to write (in this case three) try-except-clauses of which every single one adds one of the variable to the list. But I think there has to be a better way to solve this task.

How can I do this in a more elegant way?

Comment: How about replacing `self.__a`, `self.__b`, `self.__c` with a "private" dict `self.priv` containing keys `a`, `b`, `c`. Then you could `iteritems` over it.

Comment: In addition to answer below maybe change the loop to `for var in [i for i in [self.__a, self.__b, self.__c] if i]`

Comment: Why have the private variables not been set up?

Comment: @PeterWood because the check is very general, it's run at several points where variables are entered or changed, and at some point, may not all variables have been set to far. One could have initialized them with `None` on instantiating the object, but the structure of the class now already works this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
for attr in ['__a', '__b', '__c']:
    try:
        var = getattr(self, attr)
        # Do something
    except AttributeError:
        pass # or do something else
```

You can also do this:

```
NON_EXISTING = object() # put this as a global variable somewhere for reusability

for attr in ['__a', '__b', '__c']:
    var = getattr(self, attr, NON_EXISTING)
    if var is not NON_EXISTING:
        # Do something
    else: # If you just want to skip, you will not even need this
        pass # or do something else
```

Or this:

```
for attr in ['__a', '__b', '__c']:
    if hasattr(self, attr):
        var = getattr(self, attr)
        # Do something
    else:
        pass # or do something else
```

Comment: Thank you btquanto, the first part of your answer is exactly what I needed!

Comment: I prefer the second, and third (just added) part of the answer, which essentially results in the same thing. However, it does not use exception for flow control (which is a bad practice). Consider reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274310/python-using-exceptions-for-control-flow-considered-bad

Comment: Isn't it in Python "better to ask for forgiveness than for permission"?

Comment: In this case, it does not really matter, since `has_attr`, and `getattr(obj, attr, default)` are  implemented with exception handling underneath, as I remember.

Answer (score 3):

You could modify the `__getattr__` method within your class to prevent returning `AttributeError` in these cases, a la:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if hasattr(self, name):
            return object.__getattr__(self, name)
        else:
            return None
```

Obviously you could extend this to cases where `name` is in `["__a", "__b", "__c"]` or `startswith("__")`.

Then use within your method similar to before, but filter out the `None`s:

```
for var in filter(None, [self.__a, self.__b, self.__c]):
    ...
```

**Note**: You should really only do this if you know what it's doing, and you understand the risks it entails. In most cases you should `try-except` and seek forgiveness on `AttributeError`.

Comment: Hello Ian, thank you for your answer, but I need this behavior only for a subset of variables, not for all private variables inside my class. But your tip might be useful in other cases!

Comment: OK sweet, didn't know if it was really limited to `__a, __b, __c` or not, so thought I'd just let you know that you can override the lookup method if appropriate. I agree that if this isn't the case then using `hasattr()` is more appropriate :)

Comment: I really didn't know that I could do that, so I now might can use your suggestion another time.

Comment: This may work, but there are two problems: `None` does not mean non-existing attribute; and overriding `__getattr__` will affect all pieces of code that uses `Foo` class. `AttributeError` will never be thrown, and a typo in the variable's name somewhere will probably stay hidden for a very long time.

Comment: @btquanto yes, which is why I'd advise caution, but it's still useful to know how things like this work under the hood. As per my first comment, I'd stick with your solution for this *particular case*.

Comment: Note explaining this added as well :)

Comment: This should be considered bad as you cannot differentiate between variables that has None value as well as variables that were not initialized

Answer (score 0):

Something similar than what you did i.e. writing three `try/except` is to get the value if it exists or None otherwise using `getattr`.

```
obj = MyObject()
for var_name in ["__a", "__b", "__c"]:
    var = getattr(obj, var_name, None)
    if var is not None:
        do_stuff()
```

I prefer this solution over modifying the way your object behaves when asked to retrieve **any** of its attribute as the answer of @IanClark suggest

Comment: A problem with this is that a `None` value and a non-existing value are different, and need to be differentiated.

Comment: True in which case using a "special value" like you did in your answer would be better

Comment: Or we can just use `has_attr` like IanClark's answer :)